# Not able to find controls in UserControl from parent page set in accordion

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, user-controls

aspx page layout is as below

```
<asp:Content ID="PageContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="PageContent" runat="Server">
<div id="checkout_onePage" class="mainContentWrapper opcOverlayWrapper">
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        Page_ClientValidate();
    </script>
    <div id="PageOverlay" runat="server" visible="false" class="opcOverlay"></div>
 <ajax:Accordion ID="UserAccordion" runat="server" SelectedIndex="0" HeaderCssClass="accordionHeader"
        HeaderSelectedCssClass="accordionHeaderSelected" ContentCssClass="accordionContent" FadeTransitions="true" SuppressHeaderPostbacks="true" TransitionDuration="250" FramesPerSecond="40" RequireOpenedPane="true" AutoSize="None">
        <Panes>
            <ajax:AccordionPane ID="BillingInformation" runat="server">
                <Header>
                    <div id="billingAddr" class="widget billingAddressWidget aboveOpcOverlay">
                        <div class="header">
                            <h2>Billing Information</h2>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </Header>
                <Content>
                    <div class="aboveOpcOverlay">
                        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UPBilling" runat="server">
                            <ContentTemplate>
                                <div class="content floatleft">
                                    <asp:PlaceHolder ID="LoginPanel" runat="server" EnableViewState="False" Visible="false">
                                        <p class="LoginMessage">
                                            If you have previously created an account, you can
                        <asp:HyperLink ID="LoginLink" runat="server" Text="log in" EnableViewState="false" CssClass="button"></asp:HyperLink>
                                            to retrieve your saved addresses.
                                        </p>
                                    </asp:PlaceHolder>                                        
                                </div>
                            </ContentTemplate>
                        </asp:UpdatePanel>
                    </div>
                </Content>
            </ajax:AccordionPane>
            <ajax:AccordionPane ID="ShippingInformation" runat="server">
                <Header>
                    <div class="widget shippingAddressWidget aboveOpcOverlay">
                        <div class="header">
                            <h2>Shipping Information</h2>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </Header>
                <Content>
                    <asp:Panel ID="ShippingAddressPanel" runat="server" Visible="true">
                        <div class="aboveOpcOverlay">
                            <div class="content" runat="server" id="Div_Main_Shipping_Information">

                            </div>
                        </div>
                     <table>
                     <tr id="trShippingAddress" runat="server" visible="false">
                                            <td>
                                                <uc2:AddressDetails ID="ShippingAddress" runat="server" ValidationGroupName="Shipping" />
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table>
                    </asp:Panel>
                </Content>
            </ajax:AccordionPane>
        </Panes>
    </ajax:Accordion>
```

I have one usercontrol assigned in above page from there I am not able to find my div control named as Div_Main_Shipping_Information

My usercontrol code is as Below

```
 Content PageContent = (Content)this.Parent.FindControl("PageContent");
 Accordion UserAccordion = (Accordion)PageContent.FindControl("UserAccordion");
 AccordionPane shipInfoPane = UserAccordion.Panes["ShippingInformation"];
 Panel ShippingAddressPanel = (Panel)shipInfoPane.FindControl("ShippingAddressPanel");
 System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl Div_Main_Shipping_Information = (System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl)ShippingAddressPanel.FindControl("Div_Main_Shipping_Information");
```

But I am not able to find my control Accordion control, panel control or my div control.

Answer (score 0):

```
using AjaxControlToolkit;

Accordion userAccordion = (Accordion)this.Page.FindControl("UserAccordion");
AccordionPane shipInfoPane = userAccordion.Panes["ShippingInformation"];
Panel ShippingAddressPanel = (Panel)shipInfoPane.FindControl("ShippingAddressPanel");
System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl Div_Main_Shipping_Information = (System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl)ShippingAddressPanel.FindControl("Div_Main_Shipping_Information");
```

Comment: what is UserAccordion? Error as doesnot exist is coming

Comment: <ajax:Accordion ID="UserAccordion"   <--UserAccordion is the ID of your Accordion control.

Comment: so 1st I have to found UserAccordion on user control right? How could i find that

Comment: I had tried  Accordion UserAccordion = (Accordion)this.Parent.FindControl("UserAccordion"); but coming as null

Comment: I don't see any User controls in the above code snippet, but if you provide that code I am happy to take a look.

Comment: If the markup above is a user control, please include the entirety of the markup. It would be useful if you include the full or partial class code behind where you're trying to reference the Accordion, for context.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146001/discussion-between-xtremcool-and-mjw).